# If $x$ is transitive, so is $x \cup \{x\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $x$ is transitive, then so is $x \cup \{x\}$.

I need help proving this. I know that a set $A$ is transitive if every member of $A$ is a subset of $A$:

$\forall x( x \in A \rightarrow x \subset A)$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If $y \in x \cup \{ x \}$, then either $y \in x$ or $y = x$.  Handle these two cases separately to show that $y \subseteq x \cup \{ x \}$.  Don't forget that $x$ is transitive.